i2c address of raspberry pi 3b+ is changed when install own driver
I'm making a driver for DS3231 for raspberry pi 3b+ and I use I2C 1, when I use cmd sudo insmod ds3231_driver, it make the I2C address change into UU (the address of the device is 0x68), when I check the dir /proc/devices, the device name have on it. And when I remove the driver with sudo rmmod ds3231_driver, the I2C address of DS3231 become the normal with 0x68.
I have tried the wiringPi lib when the driver was installed and it caused error that the I2C was busy. And when removed the driver, it worked normally. I don't know the reason, did anyone meet the problem like this before? Please instruct me how to fix. I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

You can’t use both. What you are describing is by design, UU means the driver uses the address. With the driver in place you should have /dev/rtc, where  is the number.

By the way, the rtc-ds1307 driver already supports the DS3231. An I2C device ID "ds3231" or a device tree compatible string "maxim,ds3231" will match it.
